# Saving object to JSON file than using it back in function after reading

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, encryption, ethereum

I am completly new to node.js but have to use it in my student project that require this library: https://github.com/bitchan/eccrypto.
The goal is to encrypt file using ethereum public key, save it as JSON and than read it back to decrypt with private key:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require("crypto");
var eccrypto = require("eccrypto");

var content = fs.readFileSync('pdf_test.pdf');

var importPrivateKey = "c337ded6f56c07205fb7b391654d7d463c9e0c726869523ae6024c9bec878878"
var importPublicKey = "04730a151f545f5dcdb1c6d99fb1251f5c70f216f39ba2681bcf10db16bd582e6720bc881d51f25ffbe961df6a0af24a9d39a4db3d86a7f6b3f9bf4eaac0e4006b"

var privateKey = new Buffer(importPrivateKey, "hex");
var publicKey = new Buffer(importPublicKey, "hex");

// Encrypting the file for B.
eccrypto.encrypt(publicKey, Buffer(content)).then(function(encrypted) {
    //console.log('Encrypted message ' + JSON.stringify(encrypted));

let data = JSON.stringify(encrypted);
fs.writeFileSync('encrypted.json', data);
console.log('encryption done');

let rawData = fs.readFileSync('encrypted.json')
let encryptedContent = JSON.parse(rawData);
//console.log(encryptedContent);

 // B decrypting the file.
eccrypto.decrypt(privateKey, encryptedContent).then(function(plaintext) {
    //console.log("Decrypted message: ", plaintext.toString());

    fs.writeFile('decrypted.pdf', plaintext, function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('decryption done');
});
 });
});
```

I get following error from this code: "(node:271) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Bad input."
Everything is working when i replace "encryptedContent" variable with "encrypted" on eccrypto.decrypt function but i want to let user store encrypted object and decrypt it later with this function. How can i do that?

Comment: Yeah it works if you use the object you get from the encryption method. I don't know the structure of that object, but maybe it can't be stringified with `JSON.stringify`. Typically encryption results are `Buffers` or bytearrays, which have to be dealt with accordingly ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `encrypted` object is not exactly JSON serializable so you have to encode the buffers in some sort of JSON serializable object. Since you used hex for the private and public keys I used it as well at below. (Also the `Buffer()` constructor is depracated and not secure so I switched it to `Buffer.from()`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require("crypto");
var eccrypto = require("eccrypto");

var content = fs.readFileSync('pdf_test.pdf');;

var importPrivateKey = "c337ded6f56c07205fb7b391654d7d463c9e0c726869523ae6024c9bec878878"
var importPublicKey = "04730a151f545f5dcdb1c6d99fb1251f5c70f216f39ba2681bcf10db16bd582e6720bc881d51f25ffbe961df6a0af24a9d39a4db3d86a7f6b3f9bf4eaac0e4006b"

let privateKey = Buffer.from(importPrivateKey, 'hex');
let publicKey = Buffer.from(importPublicKey, 'hex');


// Encrypting the file for B.
eccrypto.encrypt(publicKey, Buffer.from(content)).then(function (encrypted) {
    //console.log('Encrypted message ' + JSON.stringify(encrypted));

    let data = JSON.stringify({
        iv: encrypted.iv.toString('hex'),
        ciphertext: encrypted.ciphertext.toString('hex'),
        mac: encrypted.mac.toString('hex'),
        ephemPublicKey: encrypted.ephemPublicKey.toString('hex')
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('encrypted.json', data);
    console.log('encryption done');

    let rawData = fs.readFileSync('encrypted.json')
    let encryptedContent = JSON.parse(rawData);
    encryptedContent = {
        iv: Buffer.from(encryptedContent.iv, 'hex'),
        ciphertext: Buffer.from(encryptedContent.ciphertext, 'hex'),
        mac: Buffer.from(encryptedContent.mac, 'hex'),
        ephemPublicKey: Buffer.from(encryptedContent.ephemPublicKey, 'hex')
    }
    //console.log(encryptedContent);

    // B decrypting the file.
    eccrypto.decrypt(privateKey, encryptedContent).then(function (plaintext) {
        //console.log("Decrypted message: ", plaintext.toString());

        fs.writeFile('decrypted.pdf', plaintext, function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log('decryption done');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for fast respond. I tried your solution: it create decrypted file but its some how corrupted and can not be open,

Comment: Fixed the solution sorry for that

Comment: Now everything is working as intended. Thanks for help!